# How to add extra files to installed pod xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm using `pod 'DropDown'` to this project.
I need to add more 2 files to this pod for more customized functionalities. I add those files to pod manually. But they not compiling..

Before adding files

[image]

After adding files

[image]

How to add properly.. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, How I figured out

You have to add those files to compiling sources

[image]